# "[columnname] is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Query works fine in MySQL but not in MSSQL. The fiddles:

MySQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/f1959/2

MSSQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4d276/2

Seems like the fact that MySQL is letting it work would make for a faster query because int's would be faster to search through than variable length character strings..

Comment: MySQL supports what SQL Server does not: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query works on `MySQL` because of its capability of [`Extended GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html). This behavior in `MySQL` can be restricted if you enable the [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) SQL mode.

But in `SQL Server`, you need to explicitly define all the columns in the `GROUP BY` clause that are not aggregated which are defined on the `SELECT` clause

```
SELECT t.name, COUNT(d.data)
FROM   types AS t
       LEFT JOIN data AS d ON d.typeId = t.id
GROUP  BY d.typeId, t.name;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4d276/3)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two SQL Server queries ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4d276/17)) that will give you the result you want without the need for extra GROUP BY items.

```
SELECT t.name, a.ct
FROM types AS t
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT COUNT(d.data) AS ct
  FROM data AS d
  WHERE d.typeId = t.id
) as A

SELECT
  t.name,
  (SELECT COUNT(d.data)
   FROM data AS d
   WHERE d.typeId = t.id
  ) AS ct
FROM types AS t
```

In either case (as in MySQL), you should be sure there is a 1-to-1 relationship between types.name and types.id. At least in SQL Server, the result is well-defined if that's not true. In MySQL, if there is more than one types.name value for a given types.id, you may get any of the matching names.